# Capacitated k-means clustering?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm newbie to algorithm and optimization.
I'm trying to implement **capacitated k-means**, but getting unresolved and poor result so far.
This is used as part of a CVRP simulation (capacitated vehicle routing problem).
I'm curious if I interprets the referenced algorithm wrong.

Ref: ["Improved K-Means Algorithm for Capacitated Clustering Problem"
(Geetha, Poonthalir, Vanathi)](http://www.dcc.ufla.br/infocomp/artigos/v8.4/art07.pdf)

The simulated CVRP has 15 customers, with 1 depot.
Each customer has Euclidean coordinate (x,y) and demand.
There are 3 vehicles, each has capacity of 90.

So, the capacitated k-means is trying to cluster 15 customers into 3 vehicles, with the total demands in each cluster must not exceed vehicle capacity.

**UPDATE:**

In the referenced algorithm, I couldn't catch any information about what must the code do when it runs out of "next nearest centroid".
That is, when all of the "nearest centroids" has been examined, in the **step 14.b** below, while the `customers[1]` is still unassigned.

This results in the customer with index 1 being unassigned.
Note: `customer[1]` is customer with largest demand (30).
**Q: When this condition is met, what the code should do then?**

---

Here is my interpretation of the referenced algorithm, please correct my code, thank you.

1. Given `n` requesters (customers), `n` = `customerCount`, and a depot
2. n demands,
3. n coordinates (x,y)
4. calculate number of clusters, `k` = (sum of all demands) / `vehicleCapacity`
5. select initial centroids, 
   5.a. sort customers based on `demand`, in descending order = `d_customers`, 
   5.b. select `k` first customers from `d_customers` as initial centroids = `centroids[0 .. k-1]`,
6. Create binary matrix `bin_matrix`, dimension = `(customerCount) x (k)`, 
   6.a. Fill `bin_matrix` with all zeros
7. start WHILE loop, condition = WHILE `not converged`. 
   7.a. `converged = False`
8. start FOR loop, condition = FOR `each customers`, 
   8.a. index of customer = i
9. calculate Euclidean distances from `customers[i]` to all `centroids` => `edist` 
   9.a. sort `edist` in ascending order, 
   9.b. select first `centroid` with closest distance = `closest_centroid`
10. start WHILE loop, condition = `while customers[i]` is not assigned to any cluster.
11. group all the other unassigned customers = `G`, 
    11.a. consider `closest_centroid` as centroid for `G`.
12. calculate priorities `Pi` for each `customers` of `G`, 
    12.a. Priority `Pi = (distance from customers[i] to closest_cent) / demand[i]` 
    12.b. select a customer with highest priority `Pi`. 
    12.c. customer with highest priority has index = `hpc` 
    **12.d. Q: IF highest priority customer cannot be found, what must we do ?**
13. assign `customers[hpc]` to `centroids[closest_centroid]` if possible. 
    13.a. demand of `customers[hpc]` = `d1`, 
    13.b. sum of all demands of centroids' members = `dtot`, 
    13.c. `IF (d1 + dtot) <= vehicleCapacity, THEN`.. 
    13.d. assign `customers[hpc]` to `centroids[closest_centroid]` 
    13.e. update `bin_matrix`, row index = `hpc`,  column index = `closest_centroid`, set to `1`.
14. IF `customers[i]` is (still) `not assigned` to any cluster, THEN.. 
    14.a. choose the `next nearest centroid`, with the next nearest distance from `edist`. 
    **14.b. Q: IF there is no next nearest centroid, THEN what must we do ?**
15. calculate converged by comparing previous matrix and updated matrix bin_matrix. 
    15.a. IF no changes in the `bin_matrix`, then set `converged = True`.
16. otherwise, calculate `new centroids` from updated clusters. 
    16.a. calculate new `centroids' coordinates` based on members of each cluster. 
    16.b. `sum_x` = sum of all `x-coordinate` of a cluster `members`, 
    16.c. `num_c` = number of all `customers (members)` in the cluster, 
    16.d. new centroid's `x-coordinate` of the cluster = `sum_x / num_c`. 
    16.e. with the same formula, calculate new centroid's `y-coordinate` of the cluster = `sum_y / num_c`.
17. iterate the main WHILE loop.

My code is always ended with unassigned customer at the **step 14.b**. 
That is when there is a `customers[i]` still not assigned to any centroid, and it has run out of "next nearest centroid".

And the resulting clusters is poor. Output graph:

[image]

-In the picture, star is centroid, square is depot. 
In the pic, customer labeled "1", with demand=30 always ended with no assigned cluster.

Output of the program,

```
k_cluster 3
idx [ 1 -1  1  0  2  0  1  1  2  2  2  0  0  2  0]
centroids [(22.6, 29.2), (34.25, 60.25), (39.4, 33.4)]
members [[3, 14, 12, 5, 11], [0, 2, 6, 7], [9, 8, 4, 13, 10]]
demands [86, 65, 77]
```

First and third cluster is poorly calculated. 
`idx` with index '`1`' is not assigned (`-1`)

**Q: What's wrong with my interpretation and my implementation?** 
Any correction, suggestion, help, will be very much appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# pastebin.com/UwqUrHhh
# output graph: i.imgur.com/u3v2OFt.png

import math
import random
from operator import itemgetter
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy
import pylab

# depot and customers, [index, x, y, demand]
depot = [0, 30.0, 40.0, 0]
customers = [[1, 37.0, 52.0, 7], \
             [2, 49.0, 49.0, 30], [3, 52.0, 64.0, 16], \
             [4, 20.0, 26.0, 9], [5, 40.0, 30.0, 21], \
             [6, 21.0, 47.0, 15], [7, 17.0, 63.0, 19], \
             [8, 31.0, 62.0, 23], [9, 52.0, 33.0, 11], \
             [10, 51.0, 21.0, 5], [11, 42.0, 41.0, 19], \
             [12, 31.0, 32.0, 29], [13, 5.0, 25.0, 23], \
             [14, 12.0, 42.0, 21], [15, 36.0, 16.0, 10]]
customerCount = 15
vehicleCount = 3
vehicleCapacity = 90
assigned = [-1] * customerCount

# number of clusters
k_cluster = 0
# binary matrix
bin_matrix = []
# coordinate of centroids
centroids = []
# total demand for each cluster, must be <= capacity
tot_demand = []
# members of each cluster
members = []
# coordinate of members of each cluster
xy_members = []

def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)

# capacitated k-means clustering
# http://www.dcc.ufla.br/infocomp/artigos/v8.4/art07.pdf
def cap_k_means():
    global k_cluster, bin_matrix, centroids, tot_demand
    global members, xy_members, prev_members

    # calculate number of clusters
    tot_demand = sum([c[3] for c in customers])
    k_cluster = int(math.ceil(float(tot_demand) / vehicleCapacity))
    print 'k_cluster', k_cluster

    # initial centroids = first sorted-customers based on demand
    d_customers = sorted(customers, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    centroids, tot_demand, members, xy_members = [], [], [], []
    for i in range(k_cluster):
        centroids.append(d_customers[i][1:3])   # [x,y]

        # initial total demand and members for each cluster
        tot_demand.append(0)
        members.append([])
        xy_members.append([])

    # binary matrix, dimension = customerCount-1 x k_cluster
    bin_matrix = [[0] * k_cluster for i in range(len(customers))]

    converged = False
    while not converged:  # until no changes in formed-clusters
        prev_matrix = deepcopy(bin_matrix)

        for i in range(len(customers)):
            edist = []  # list of distance to clusters

            if assigned[i] == -1:  # if not assigned yet
                # Calculate the Euclidean distance to each of k-clusters
                for k in range(k_cluster):
                    p1 = (customers[i][1], customers[i][2]) # x,y
                    p2 = (centroids[k][0], centroids[k][1])
                    edist.append((distance(p1, p2), k))

                # sort, based on closest distance
                edist = sorted(edist, key=itemgetter(0))

            closest_centroid = 0    # first index of edist
            # loop while customer[i] is not assigned
            while assigned[i] == -1:  
                # calculate all unsigned customers (G)'s priority
                max_prior = (0, -1)   # value, index
                for n in range(len(customers)):
                    pc = customers[n]

                    if assigned[n] == -1:   # if unassigned
                        # get index of current centroid
                        c = edist[closest_centroid][1]
                        cen = centroids[c]     # x,y

                        # distance_cost / demand
                        p = distance((pc[1], pc[2]), cen) / pc[3]

                        # find highest priority
                        if p > max_prior[0]:
                            max_prior = (p, n)  # priority,customer-index

                # if highest-priority is not found, what should we do ???
                if max_prior[1] == -1:   
                    break

                # try to assign current cluster to highest-priority customer
                hpc = max_prior[1]    # index of highest-priority customer
                c = edist[closest_centroid][1]   # index of current cluster

                # constraint, total demand in a cluster <= capacity
                if tot_demand[c] + customers[hpc][3] <= vehicleCapacity:
                    # assign new member of cluster
                    members[c].append(hpc)   # add index of customer

                    xy = (customers[hpc][1], customers[hpc][2])  # x,y
                    xy_members[c].append(xy)

                    tot_demand[c] += customers[hpc][3]
                    assigned[hpc] = c   # update cluster to assigned-customer

                    # update binary matrix
                    bin_matrix[hpc][c] = 1

                # if customer is not assigned then,
                if assigned[i] == -1:
                    if closest_centroid < len(edist)-1:
                        # choose the next nearest centroid
                        closest_centroid += 1

                    # if run out of closest centroid, what must we do ???
                    else:
                        break   # exit without centroid ???

            # end while
        # end for

        # Calculate the new centroid from the formed clusters
        for j in range(k_cluster):
            xj = sum([cn[0] for cn in xy_members[j]])
            yj = sum([cn[1] for cn in xy_members[j]])
            xj = float(xj) / len(xy_members[j])
            yj = float(yj) / len(xy_members[j])
            centroids[j] = (xj, yj)

        # calculate converged
        converged = numpy.array_equal(numpy.array(prev_matrix), numpy.array(bin_matrix))
    # end while

def clustering():
    cap_k_means()

    # debug plot
    idx = numpy.array([c for c in assigned])
    xy = numpy.array([(c[1], c[2]) for c in customers])

    COLORS = ["Blue", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkTurquoise", 
          "IndianRed", "MediumVioletRed", "Orange", "Purple"]

    for i in range(min(idx), max(idx)+1):
        clr = random.choice(COLORS)
        pylab.plot(xy[idx==i, 0], xy[idx==i, 1], color=clr, \
            linestyle='dashed', \
            marker='o', markerfacecolor=clr, markersize=8)
    pylab.plot(centroids[:][0], centroids[:][1], '*k', markersize=12)
    pylab.plot(depot[1], depot[2], 'sk', markersize=12)

    for i in range(len(idx)):
        pylab.annotate(str(i), xy[i])

    pylab.savefig('clust1.png')
    pylab.show()

    return idx

def main():
    idx = clustering()
    print 'idx', idx
    print 'centroids', centroids
    print 'members', members
    print 'demands', tot_demand

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am resisting the urge to downvote - this is way too much info. Would you settle for sorting index 1 being unassigned?

Comment: @doctorlove Thank you very much for the response. I've updated my question above, right after "UPDATE" section. 
(sorry for possible misunderstand your comment, I'm not native English speaker, so I have little doubt about the meaning of "settle for sorting", even after I Google translate the phrase, very sorry, thank you.)

Comment: s/sorting/"deal with the problem of"

Comment: @doctorlove Thank you, does my update satisfy your question? Please correct me if I still provided less information needed, thanks.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you very much for editing my question, so that the picture of output graph can be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the total demand is close to the total capacity, this problem begins to take on aspects of [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). As you've discovered, this particular algorithm's greedy approach is not always successful. I don't know whether the authors admitted that, but if they didn't, the reviewers should have caught it.

If you want to continue with something like this algorithm, I would try using [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) to assign requesters to centroids.

Comment: I understand it. Thank you very much. I'll switch to mixed integer programming then.

Answer (score 0):

Without going through all the details, the paper you cite says

```
 if ri is not assigned then
     choose the next nearest centroid
 end if
```

in the algorithm at the end of section 5.

There must be a next nearest centroid - if two are equidistant I presume it doesn't matter which you choose.

Comment: Thank you very much. I store the next nearest centroids in a list. There are at most 3 nearest centroids. In my case, all 3 as the next nearest centroids has been chosen, while the customer[1] is still unassigned. It does "cross" assignment, based on the "self and other" unassigned-customers with highest priority, so customer[1] never has a chance to be assigned, due to it has lower priority, even until there is no more "next nearest centroids" (already hit the third index of nearest centroids). Thanks.

Comment: Ouch - hopefully someone else who knows this variant of the algo will step in and help

Comment: Thank you so much because you've examined, answered and commented my problem, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with fixed-size clustering is that you can often identify 'swaps' in the output, where swapping 2 points between clusters creates a better solution.

We can improve the constrained k-means algorithm from the referenced paper by formulating the 'find the cluster to assign the point to' as an *assignment problem*, instead of greedily picking the nearest one that isn't full.

A common way to solve this is using a *min-cost flow* algorithm. The result of this guarantees that there aren't any 'swaps' available that improve the result.

Luckily, someone has already implemented this and created a package for it: https://github.com/joshlk/k-means-constrained

Check out [Bradley, P. S., Bennett, K. P., & Demiriz, A. (2000). Constrained k-means clustering.](http://machinelearning102.pbworks.com/f/ConstrainedKMeanstr-2000-65.pdf)

One side note, is that customers with a very large demand may still not be able to be assigned to a single depot, so the value of *k* may need to be increased a until there is a feasible solution, or 'splitting' the demand of a customer between multiple depots needs to be allowed.